# How to say "this" in "This is my third time in Taiwan"?

Tags: measure-word

Several times I've told people that I'm Taiwan for the third time and everybody understood me just fine, but I'm not sure I'm saying it right.

這個是我的三次在臺灣

I know 次 is the word for "time" in this sense, and I know it's also a counter word for times.

So is my choice correct for "this"? I said 這個 with the generic counter word, but should I really say 這次 since I'm discussing times, or is just plain 這 best?

Or should I really express it in an entirely different way?

Comment: *這（次）是我第三次來臺灣。*
Both with and without 次 are acceptable.
In addition, English uses "in", so you used "在臺灣".
However, we prefer using "來臺灣".

Comment: @young99: Thanks! We also say "This is my third time to Taiwan" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say something like:

> 這是我第三次到臺灣來
>
> *This is my third time coming to Taiwan*

You do not say「這個」, because the measure word (in this situation) for travelling/trips is「次」(which you've already said) and not「個」.

Answer (score 1):

這（次）是我第三次來台灣

次 is often omitted. You need 第  as it’s the **third** time not **three** times.